# How to install apache ant

Tags: apache-http-server

I have download apache ant zip file. and intall into -> C://

Same location have Java.

I have set environment variable
like

KEy   Value

```
ANT_HOME C:\apache-ant-1.9.4
JAVA_HOME C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre
PATH  %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_H0ME%\bin;%path%
```

But when checking in cmd ant -version. It is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I have it installed and my enviroment variables are:

ANT_ROOT D:\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin

It is pointing to another folder (bin), try changing it and see if your system recognizes it.
Also remember to close the console and reopen it so it reloads the enviroment variables.